# Static page with scrollable division with Tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css

What i want is the whole page to be static and division with paragraph to be scrollable. At the moment main page is also scrollable because of masthead. How to prevent this?
Code snippet:

```
    <main class="flex flex-col h-screen">
        <div class="flex bg-blue-300 h-32 ">Masthead</div>
        <div class="flex flex-row h-full">
            <div class="bg-gray-100 w-32 p-4">Sidebar</div>
            <div class="flex flex-col bg-white flex-grow">
                <div class="bg-gray-300 h-16 p-4">
                    <p>Header</p>
                </div>
                <div class="paragraph overflow-y-auto px-4">
                    @for($i=1; $i < 200; $i++)
                    <p>paragraph</p>
                    @endfor
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Please provide the CSS styles too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always preferred to use `flex flex-col flex-1` combination to achieve such layout. Checkout [Tailwind Layout](https://play.tailwindcss.com/piInPJXoKq) I created for better understanding.

```
<main class="flex flex-col h-screen">
  <div class="flex h-32 bg-blue-300">Masthead</div>
  <div class="flex flex-1 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="flex bg-gray-100 w-32 p-4">Sidebar</div>
    <div class="flex flex-1 flex-col">
      <div class="flex bg-gray-300 h-16 p-4">Header</div>
      <div class="flex flex-1 bg-blue-300 overflow-y-auto paragraph px-4">
         @for($i=1; $i < 200; $i++)
           <p>paragraph</p>
         @endfor
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">Footer</div>
</main>
```